# Why is direct-list-initialization with auto considered bad or not preferred?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, auto, type-deduction

I've come into the habit of writing code with direct-list-initialization like below as it's more effective and it's very useful to prevent implicit [narrowing](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#narrowing):

```
int i {0};
string s {""};
char c {'a'};
bool b {false};

auto num {100}; // But this??
```

But when it comes to the auto specifier, I have heard it is considered bad or not preferred to write it like that, why is that?

Comment: There are a bunch of defects and oddities around curly braces. E.g. `int n; int & r { n };` used to be broken. And the degeneration of `auto x = { 1, 2 }` to `auto y = { 1 }` may be surprising. Basically, curly braces introduce a lot of non-uniformity that some people consider not worth confusing your readers with.

Comment: highly recommend: [herb Sutter: Almost Always Auto](http://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/)

Comment: Type deduction is exactly the problem. Curly braces have many different meanings and you want the compiler to deduce what you want to do on the right site but also to deduce type of that on the left side. This means if the deduction has surprising result on the right side (especially because the compiler does not know what you want as there is no result type known), the left side will automatically accept the result and no check will tell you that something is wrong.

Comment: If the standards committee would put tuple literals in the core language this wouldn't be as big of an issue. The type system handling of `initializer_list` is a bad joke. It works how you expect it to except when it doesn't.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's an example of where using that syntax fails:

```
struct Foo{};

void eatFoo (const Foo& f){}

int main() {
    Foo a;
    auto b{a};
    eatFoo(b);
}
```

You might expect this to be fine: `b` should be a `Foo` and be passed to `eatFoo`. Unfortunately, this results in the following compiler error:

```
prog.cpp:11:10: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'const Foo&' from expression of type 'std::initializer_list<Foo>'
  eatFoo(b);
```

As you can see, `b` is actually of type `std::initializer_list<Foo>`. Certainly not what we want in this case. If we change it to `auto b = a`, this works fine. Then if we want to still use `auto`, but explicitly state the type, we can change it to `auto b = Foo{a}` and let the compiler elide the copy.

Comment: Hopefully this will be fixed in C++17: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3912.html

Comment: "Then if we want to still use `auto`, but explicitly state the type," -- That really doesn't make sense. The whole point of `auto` is avoiding stating the type. I know in C# there are really people who write `var x = (string) null;` rather than `string x = null;`, but they're a tiny fraction and I've never seen anyone actually defend writing code like that. I can't imagine a valid argument for it in C++ either.

Comment: It's part of the [Almost Always Auto style](http://herbsutter.com/2013/08/12/gotw-94-solution-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/). Since it has discussion from some pretty influential people, it seems pertinent to include it.

Comment: @TartanLlama Thanks for the link. One thing that isn't mentioned there outside of the comments, and in my opinion a very strong reason *against* that style, is that it enables explicit conversion operators. Those conversion operators are generally explicit for good reasons, they should not be used by default, only when the user explicitly requests them. For instance, given `struct S { explicit S(int); };`, `S s = 3;` fails to compile. `auto s = S{3};` is accepted. Systematically using the `auto v = T{i};` syntax means the compiler gets less opportunities to warn you about possible mistakes.

Comment: Yes, that's a really good argument against it. I guess the core of this argument is that the AAA style has no equivalent to explicitly-typed copy-initialization for defensively programming around these issues.

Comment: @hvd `auto x = std::make_unique<SomeTypeName>(bla...);` is better than repeating the type

Comment: @MattMcNabb That's different, `std::make_unique<SomeTypeName>` is a function, not a type. And yes, I do agree with the use of `auto` there.

Comment: @TartanLlama interesting example... I just found out that g++5 does the "right" job here (i.e. copy, not init_list). clang++ fails though.

Comment: @MattMcNabb: `auto x = std::make_unique<SomeTypeName>(bla...);` does NOT state the type (`std::unique_ptr<SomeTypeName>`), it's inferred from the return type of `make_unique`.

Comment: @BenVoigt I am talking about `SomeTypeName`

Comment: @MattMcNabb: But the discussion is about "use `auto` but explicitly state the type", and your snippet is not an example of that.  Naming `SomeTypeName` is not explicitly stating the type of the `auto` variable.