# auto rules for direct-list-initialization

Tags: c++, c++17

I was just trying to learn the new c++17 changes related "auto rules for direct-list-initialization"

Few of the stackoverflow  question thread has answers like its not a safe thing to do 
[Why is direct-list-initialization with auto considered bad or not preferred?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29890918/why-is-direct-list-initialization-with-auto-considered-bad-or-not-preferred)

Tried one of the selected answer to understand

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

struct Foo{};

void eatFoo (const Foo& f){}

int main() {
    Foo a;
    auto b{a};
    eatFoo(b);
    std::cout << "a " << typeid(a).name() << '\n';
    std::cout << "b " << typeid(b).name() << '\n';

}
```

But to my surprise it compiled without any warning or compile error
output

```
a 3Foo
b 3Foo
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Does it mean now its safe to use auto for direct initialization

for example like this

```
auto x { 1 };
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Safe" is in the eye of the beholder.

C++14's behavior was "safe", in that it was well-defined what the result would be. `auto var_name{expr}` would create an `initializer_list` of one element.

C++17 makes it so that `auto var_name{expr}` results in the same type deduction as `auto var_name = expr;` would have. So long as you expect this to be the case, then it is "safe". But it is no more "safe" than the old behavior.

Then again, this is a language change that is backwards-incompatible with the C++14 behavior. By that standard, it is not "safe", in that a C++14 user will *expect* your code to be doing something different than it is under a C++17 compiler. So it creates some subtle confusion, which may not be safe.

Then there's the issue that "uniform initialization" is supposed to be "uniform" (ie: performs the same kind of initialization under the same rules in all places), yet `auto var_name{expr}` will do something very different from `auto var_name = {expr}`. The latter will still be an `initializer_list`; the former will be a copy/move. By that token, it is not "safe" to assume that "uniform initialization" is uniform.

Then again, the C++17 behavior is sometimes the thing you really wanted. That initializing a variable from a single value, to you, means to copy/move it. After all, if you had done `decltype(expr) var_name{expr}`, that's the behavior you'd get. So from that perspective, it could seem to be "safe" behavior.

At the very least, we can say that the situation is more teachable through two rules:

1. Direct-list-initialization of `auto` variables means "copy/move the expression into the variable, and if you provide more than one expression, you're using the wrong syntax."
2. Copy-list-initialization of `auto` variables means "make an `initializer_list`, and if you provide values that can't do that, you're using the wrong syntax."

Perhaps the simplicity creates a sense of "safety".

[The document](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3681.html) that instigated these changes makes a case that you're less likely to get accidental UB by returning a stack-bound `initializer_list` by sticking to the above rules. That's one definition of "safe".

So it all depends on what you mean by "safe".

Comment: Really want to link a clip of Obiwan  explaining "true" to Luke here.

Comment: auto x1 = { 1, 2 }; // error: cannot have multiple elements in a braced-init-list with auto . but now we can have that
std::initializer_list<int> f()
{
     auto x1 = {1,2}; // ill-formed, {1,2} is not an expression
     return x1;
}

int main()
{
    auto y = f();
    
}

Comment: @HariomSingh: ... I'm not really sure what you're trying to say there.